# Do namespace declarations within included files automatically include the parent file's namespace (PHP)?

Tags: php, namespaces

Should be a simple question. I do not yet have 5.3 installed, so I cannot experiment myself.

When declaring a namespace in an included file, do I have to declare the full path of the namespace, or is the parent namespace already assumed to be included?

For instance, if I have a file:

```
// file1.php
<?php
    namespace parent_space;
    include 'file2.php';
?>
```

and a second file:

```
// file2.php
<?php
    namespace child_space;
    // some code
?>
```

Since `file2.php` is included from within the `parent_space` namespace in `file1.php`, is the namespace for "some code" `\parent_space\child_space\` , or is it just `\child_space\` ?

Comment: This is what the documentations says: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.faq.php#language.namespaces.faq.conflict

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. PHP does not attach any significance to the *location* of your file when including, but it does treat each file as a completely separate entity as far as namespaces are concerned when parsing the code.

So this code will not work:

```
<?php
    namespace Food; //this is a top level namespace
    include 'file2.php';

//file2.php
<?php
    namespace Tacos; //this is still a top level namespace
```

You would need to define your file2.php in this manner:

```
<?php

namespace Food\Tacos;
```

Reference the PHP manual for more information about namespaces: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php

Answer (score 0):

There are some similar examples in the PHP manual namespace section:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php

The short answer is: no.

Comment: I am assuming by no, you mean the second namespace possibility I proposed is used?

Comment: Yes. The no is an answer to the question in your title.