# CakePHP 3: Class 'Configure' Not Found

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.1

I just started with CakePHP v3.1.3 yesterday and I'm migrating teeny tiny bits of my CakePHP 2.4.2 site over at a time. Mostly just trying to get an understanding of the changes. I'm having an issue with `Configure::read()`.

A little background info: I have **SettingsSite**, **SettingsSiteHeaders**, and **SettingsSitesOptions** tables in my db, I also made corresponding table objects for those. In my SettingsSiteTable class I have a method that retrieves the settings stored in the database. All is well and the following code works in my **AppController** no problem.

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use Cake\Controller\Controller;
use Cake\Event\Event;
use Cake\Core\Configure;

class AppController extends Controller{

    public function beforeFilter(Event $event){
        debug(Configure::read('SettingsSite.title'));
    }
```

I'm having an issue getting the value to display properly in my view.

I have the following code in my theme default layout located in **plugins/Default/src/Template/Layout/default.ctp**

```
<title>
    <?php
        echo $this->fetch('title') . ' | ' .
        Configure::read('SettingsSite.title');
    ?>
</title>
```

I was receiving a "**Class 'Configure' not found in plugins/Default/src/Template/Layout/default.ctp**" error message.

So I then went to the **AppView.php** file and added the following line under the namespace declaration:

```
use Cake\Core\Configure;
```

Error is still there.

Comment: Put `use Cake\Core\Configure;` in your layout file. For a reason why see this questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667796/do-namespace-declarations-within-included-files-automatically-include-the-parent

Comment: @ankr ...that kind of sucks to have to do. The cook book says "You can access Configure from anywhere in your application: Configure::read('debug');" And we used to not have to do this in version 2. Also, I tried placing it in my default.ctp layout file thinking it would apply to every view that uses the template but it doesn't. It's very inconvenient to have to put this inside of EVERY view file. There has to be a better way.

Comment: If it is being the SettingsSite.title is being used on every page, why not set it as a view variable in app controller?

Comment: That's simply how PHP namespace imports work, it's a per-file feature.

Comment: Cake 3 use namespaces and Cake 2 didn't, and as @ndm mentions this is behavior of PHP rather than Cake. An option is to use a Helper to get the information you want - if nothing else then just as a proxy for `Configure`.

Comment: But the fact that you use `Configure` in "every file" sounds like there might be better options, such as sending the data from the controller or using a helper as mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks everyone. In my SettingsSiteTable object I decided to return the array of settings instead of saving them via Configure::write(). I am then able to store the results in a view variable.

Comment: Sounds like a better solution @bowlerae (Y) Good luck!

Comment: @chrisShick this is exactly what I did. If you want to put that in an answer I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just simply make your Settings a view variable in the app controller's beforeFilter :)

Comment: Never  beforeFilter, beforeRender is the correct one IMO.

Answer (score 7):

Just use

```
use Cake\Core\Configure;
```

on top of your controller

Also If you have custom config file in app folder. You can load it in Bootstrap file and load the Config like this;

```
$config = Configure::read('App.namespace');
debug($config);
```

Answer (score 2):

On your layout use the below line. This worked for me:

```
<?php use Cake\Core\Configure; ?>

<title>
    <?php
        echo $this->fetch('title') . ' | ' .
        Configure::read('SettingsSite.title');
    ?>
</title>
```

Comment: Or just use a helper wrapper for it :) [Shim.Configure helper](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-shim/blob/master/src/View/Helper/ConfigureHelper.php) - no need for use statements then.